# Problema en Consola PowerShel ModuleNotFoundError Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, consola, powershell

Tengo el siguiente problema: Cuando trato de correr un test con Selenium Webdriver hecho con Python y Unittest en la consola del powerShell me tira lo siguente: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'page_objects'

```
PS C:\Users\verti> cd D:\Proyect\La_Pelu\tests
PS D:\Proyect\La_Pelu\tests> python -m test_elimination_sale_associated_with_product.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program\Python3.8\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Program\Python3.8\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "D:\Proyect\La_Pelu\tests\test_elimination_sale_associated_with_product.py", line 5, in <module>
    from page_objects.pageindex import Pageindex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'page_objects'
PS D:\Proyect\La_Pelu\tests>
```

Un detalle, este mismo test lo corrí anteriormente en el PowerShell y me funciono bien, la diferencia es que antes tenia los archivos de pruebas y el driver juntos y ahora los separe en python package.

Lo curioso que en el IDE Pycharm funcionan perfecto, alguna sujerencia?

Answer (score 0):

El error te está diciendo que "page_objects" no se encuentra entre tus archivos, es decir estás intentando importar un archivo, que no existe.

Probablemente al separar los archivos, hayas cambiado algunos de lugar, y no puedas importarlos, puesto que ya no se encuentran en la carpeta raiz del módulo